# Dynamically creating Content pages with different content on each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web

I have created a website in which a menu has around 200 submenus.I have to show some relevant text for each submenuitem.I have a master page and few content  pages.I don't want to create 200 content pages for submenus .Is there is some way to do it efficiently.The approach may be database driven or dynamically creating content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each menu item should refer to the same page but with different parameter. For example:

```
content.aspx?id=5
```

Inside the page you just need to read parameter:

```
int id = 0;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id);
if (id != 0)
{
// load the corresponding content
}
```

Comment: Means you are saying to change the content of the same page dynamically.But how can i show different pafe names in url.Say for id=1 it shows http://xxx/xxx/submenu1.aspx for id=2 http://xxx/xxx/submenu2.aspx etc

Comment: You said in your post you don't want 200 pages. I suggest to have only one (or several probably if theirs content is too different). How many pages do you want to have? For the given sample, should xxx/xxx/submenu1.aspx and xxx/xxx/submenu2.aspx be different? If not, one page would be enough. If yes, just create 2 different pages submenu1.aspx and submenu2.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the id number of the page from the URL, then query the database for that item either using direct T-SQL or calling a stored procedure.

You should store all your items in the database by page/post ID then you can query the DB each time you want to load a new page. That way you aren't ever pulling back more data than you need.